# Close a MySQL connection using PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to learn PHP OOP and have come upon a problem. I'm trying to open and close connection using OOP like this

```
class db{
    public  function opendb(){
        $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
        $db = mysql_select_db("test",$server) or die ("Couldn't connect to database");
        mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
        mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");    
    }

public function closedb(){
        mysql_close($server);   
    }   
}
```

and use this code in my PHP page

```
$x = new db;
$x->closedb();
```

and make queries like this

```
$x = new db;
$x->opendb();
```

but I get an error because the `$server` is not accessible from inside the second function. How can I do that?

Comment: put $server as class variable?

Comment: Please, _please_, if you want to learn OO, or PHP in general, don't learn the extensions of yesteryear: `mysql_*` is deprecated, don't use it. And when writing OO classes, try to write code that conforms to [the standard](http://www.php-fig.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you're learning, I'll keep this quite basic. Ask yourself these questions:

- What does my class do?
- what methods will go into this class, and what binds them together (what do they have in common)
- How is my class going to be used, and how will it communicate its state with the user

The answer to the first question is simple: your class will manage the DB connection and queries.

This also answers the second question, to some extent: the DB connection is required by each method, if those methods are to work. All the methods need access to a db connection, hence, the connection must have class scope (ie: it ***must*** be a property).

The last question, I'm not going to discuss in great detail, but common sense dictates that a back-end class doesn't communicate to the client directly (classes like this shouldn't `echo`, `exit` or `die`). A serious problem (like not being able to connect to the DB) should be communicated to the user (the code that invokes your class) in such a way that it cannot be ignored: throw `Exception`'s: the calling code can't ignore those.

Now we have the basics lined out, let's get to the actual code (following the conventions I linked to in my comment, and not using `mysql_*` because it's depreacted):

```
class Db
{
    /**
     * @var \PDO
     */
    protected $conn = null;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass, array $options = array())
    {
        $this->conn = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,$options);
        if (!isset($options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE]))
            $this->conn->setAttribute(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
        if ($this->conn->inTransaction())
            $this->conn->commit();
        $this->conn = null;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now, if you don't understand all of this code, then don't worry: [The manual explains all of the methods I've used](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Also be aware of the fact that the code I posted here is, IMHO, utterly pointless. I've already explained why in great detail on codereview.stackexchange. [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/very-simple-php-pdo-class/29394#29394), [also here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/do-you-see-any-flaws-in-these-prepared-statements-to-avoid-sql-injection/38587#38587), and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45147/want-to-check-if-i-am-using-pdo-correctly/45192#45192)... But if you care/want to, you can read through a couple of other code-reviews of mine concerning *wrappers*, which is essentially, what you are writing.

They may be verbose, and not directly related to what you're trying to do, but who knows: they may be useful to you in the future.